# I need to figure out on how to achieve a show/hide password

Tags: view, powerapp, login, powerapps-canvas, password

I have a login form, everything else works except for the part where I want the View icon to show/hide the password entered. The mode of the input now is TextMode.Password. It's automatically masked when typing the password. I can't really figure out how to use this icon to make it show the password on select.
[image]

Can someone help me please? Powerapps is still pretty confusing for me. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be achieved using a variable and few formulas. Follow below steps.

1. OnStart of an App: `Set(varIsPasswordMode, true)`
2. Mode property of Text Input: `If(!varIsPasswordMode, TextMode.SingleLine, TextMode.Password)`
3. OnSelect of Show Password image: `Set(varIsPasswordMode, false)`
4. OnSelect of Hide Password image: `Set(varIsPasswordMode, true)`

Comment: This technique worked, thank you very much !!

Answer (score 0):

My approach is quite similar to Asad's but there are a couple of differences.

1. Create an icon.
2. Set the icon's `OnSelect` property to

> UpdateContext({locShowPassword: !locShowPassword})

3. Set the icon's `Icon` property to

   > If(
   > locShowPassword,
   > Icon.Hide,
   > Icon.View )
4. Set the password text input box's `Mode` property to

   > If(
   > locShowPassword,
   > TextMode.SingleLine,
   > TextMode.Password )

Comment: I just checked it and this technique also worked. It's somehow a bit more easier? since I only have to put one icon, thank you very much !!